# PouchDB.find pagination solution

Tags: pagination, pouchdb

I am trying to find the best solution to paginate with PouchDB-find plugin.

for now I am using the options: "limit" and "skip" to paginate my results but this solution is not recommended for large collections: https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html#finding-documents-using-an-index and https://pouchdb.com/2014/04/14/pagination-strategies-with-pouchdb.html.

I know PouchDB-find is inspired by Cloudant which offers a "bookmark" option to help with pagination. 
Any idea if "bookmark" is available on PouchDB-find or if it will be implemented soon ?